# derby clob exception using an SQL select statement or suggest me another derby data type with no length setting

Tags: sql, select, derby, clob

I'm trying to search a clob type column for some text value, SQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM APP.Stuff where MyClob='sometext'
```

When executing the statement I get:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Comparisons between 'CLOB (UCS_BASIC)' and 'CHAR (UCS_BASIC)' are not supported. Types must be comparable. String types must also have matching collation. If collation does not match, a possible solution is to cast operands to force them to the default collation (e.g. SELECT tablename FROM sys.systables WHERE CAST(tablename AS VARCHAR(128)) = 'T1')
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
        at ca.sqlpower.sql.jdbcwrapper.StatementDecorator.execute(StatementDecorator.java:109)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
        at ca.sqlpower.swingui.query.SQLQueryUIComponents$DefaultStatementExecutor.executeStatement(SQLQueryUIComponents.java:523)
        at ca.sqlpower.swingui.query.SQLQueryUIComponents$ExecuteSQLWorker.doStuff(SQLQueryUIComponents.java:437)
        at ca.sqlpower.swingui.SPSwingWorker.run(SPSwingWorker.java:104)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Comparisons between 'CLOB (UCS_BASIC)' and 'CHAR (UCS_BASIC)' are not supported. Types must be comparable. String types must also have matching collation. If collation does not match, a possible solution is to cast operands to force them to the default collation (e.g. SELECT tablename FROM sys.systables WHERE CAST(tablename AS VARCHAR(128)) = 'T1')
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
        ... 14 more
    Caused by: ERROR 42818: Comparisons between 'CLOB (UCS_BASIC)' and 'CHAR (UCS_BASIC)' are not supported. Types must be comparable. String types must also have matching collation. If collation does not match, a possible solution is to cast operands to force them to the default collation (e.g. SELECT tablename FROM sys.systables WHERE CAST(tablename AS VARCHAR(128)) = 'T1')
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.BinaryComparisonOperatorNode.bindComparisonOperator(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.BinaryComparisonOperatorNode.bindExpression(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.SelectNode.bindExpressions(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bindExpressions(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.CursorNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
        ... 8 more
```

Why I use clob instead of VARCHAR ?
Cause I need unlimited length of text.

How do I set the parameters?
Initially I set the clob's column with this line:

```
psmt.setString(1, value);
```

then I tried:

```
psmt.setClob(1, new Clob(null, value));
```

1) What I'm a doing wrong ?

2) What other data type can I use instead of clob, where it doesn't requires setting the length ?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
SELECT * FROM APP.Stuff where MyClob LIKE 'sometext'
```